# Mysql Sum Value of a Varchar Column that Holds date in the following format into months

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a  Mysql column named weekly periods (varchar )and the dates inside the column are listed in the following format   startperiod-Endperiod.

```
weekly_periods         Amount
01/01/16 - 10/01/16    100 
11/01/16 - 17/01/16    20
18/01/16 - 24/01/16    10
25/01/16 - 31/01/16    300
01/02/16 - 07/02/16    250
08/02/16 - 14/02/16    100
```

Any ideas on the best way  to Sum the value's and Group by month for the above table ?

Trying to get the output as below .

```
January :430    February:350
```

Comment: *groans*... why would you do this to yourself?

Comment: Can we assume all periods start and end in the same month?

Comment: Will there be an overlapping of dates between months? say, can there be an entry with 15/01/2016 - 10/02/2016?

Comment: Yes  since its based on Payperiods, the standard 52 pay periods.
So i'm trying to  sum the pay periods to the nearest month .

4 periods per month .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(weekly_periods, 8), '%d/%m/%Y')) AS PeriodYear
     , MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(weekly_periods, 8), '%d/%m/%Y')) AS PeriodMonth
     , SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY PeriodYear, PeriodMonth;
```

Output:

```
| PeriodYear | PeriodMonth | TotalAmount |
|------------|-------------|-------------|
|       2016 |           1 |         430 |
|       2016 |           2 |         350 |
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ea60e/1/0)

Comment: 23/01/17-29/01/17    500
    30/01/17-05/02/17    200

It causes the  value  of 700 to appear in January and nothing appear in february ..

Any idea on how to fix that

Comment: @user3548161 I specifically [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671120/mysql-sum-value-of-a-varchar-column-that-holds-date-in-the-following-format-into/41671204?noredirect=1#comment70539768_41671120) about that. You [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671120/mysql-sum-value-of-a-varchar-column-that-holds-date-in-the-following-format-into/41671204?noredirect=1#comment70539854_41671120) that it was not an issue.

Comment: Yeah true  @shmosel  i found my logic was at error ,  after using that for a while i figured out it would be better to have data  grouped so that it does not over lap .